# Обработка многовариантных вопросов Orange

Tags: anaconda, анализ, data-mining

Подскажите как обрабатывать многовариантные вопросы в [Orange](https://orange.biolab.si/)? Например: есть база данных, составленная на основании опроса.
Формулировка вопроса:

*1. Где вы отдыхаете на выходных? (Максимум 3 варианта ответа)*

*1) Дома*

*2) На даче*

*3) В городе*

*4) На работе*

База данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Логика базы: три варианта ответа - три колонки. Порядок ответов респондента не имеет значения. 
Есть ли возможность в Orange построить гистограмму частот сразу по трем колонкам одновременно?